# Ctrl+Shift+T not working in shading tab

Tags: texturing, shaders

I am trying to follow a youtuber's tutorial on how to add textures to the asset folder, but only get the directory window which is shown on the left.

I did it once, but something went wrong (basically all the selected files were combined in one texture node and couldn't get it separated) and decided to do it again, but I can't get to the original open window when using the shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Blender won't allow me to drag and drop the texture to either the main window or node window. How do I get to the window where I can select "Principled Texture set" again?

I am using Blender 3.6.2 and Windows 11 and node wrangler already enabled

[image: shading tab]

Comment: Hello, you're probably talking about the Node Wrangler addon shortcuts? You need to enable the addon first

Comment: Hi there, that is already enabled

Comment: Please add a link to the tutorial! You can right-click the video at the place where you want the tutorial to start from and choose "Copy video URL at current time". That way we don't have to watch the entire video to see the part you're talking about.

Comment: Here is the link to the tutorial: https://youtu.be/nlfX3cL1BZk

Comment: weird, make sure that the cursor is over the Shader Editor window when you press the shortcut?

Comment: Yes, the cursor is over the window while pressing the shortcut

Comment: @moonboots & Richie: Guys, a quick glance at the screenshot shows, the _Shader Editor_ is empty, nothing mysterious here...

Comment: I think there is a bug in Blender that's causing all sorts of problems, unless there's something wrong with my computer

Comment: If Gordon's answer is not good, maybe check your shortcuts?

Comment: @Richie as Gordon has pointed out your Shader editor is empty. You did not even add a material, then how do you expect the shortcut to work. Click the *New* button first.

Comment: @Henry McKenzie, there is a sphere in the middle of the screenshot I posted, and even when the node is added as per Gordon's screenshot, the shortcut doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshot there are no nodes visible in the *Shader Editor*. Even worse: it says "New" at the top, meaning there is no material at all. First you have to create a new material, otherwise there is no nodetree which you could add nodes to.

[image: shader editor comparison]

Comment: +1 it's funny nobody realized there is no material in his editor. it's empty.

Comment: He also has the World selected in the Data properties area rather than the Material so he's in the wrong section to add a material there!

Comment: @JohnEason Since he is going to use the shortcut in the _Shader Editor_ where you can just as easy add a material nodetree as you can in _Geometry Nodes_ by clicking the "New" button, it is completely irrelevant if he is in the _World Properties_ tab, because the sphere was the the last selected object as you can see in the _3D Viewport_.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Well, I always try to look for hints in the screenshots if there are some, because I think always asking for a file upload is not worth the fuss for such simple things and a waste of server space.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Fair enough, but I thought I'd mention it in case he was expecting to see an added material appearing there.

Comment: @JohnEason Why should he, he's not even realized there is missing one. I'm sorry for being sarcastic 

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann That's true! I'll try not to be so picky next time :^)

Comment: @JohnEason ...and if he clicked "New" in the _Shader Editor_ and later realizes he's in the wrong properties, switching to the correct ones will then show the material. Whatever. The question was why does the shortcut not work, and this is totally independent from the properties.

Comment: Sorry for this, as you can imagine, I'm a total noob at this